# Google Charts Trendline: can I draw it in URL

Tags: html, url, google-visualization

I am using google charts to describe the datas. And I would like to show it in URL, which will be much easier to be added to a web page.
However, the official tutorial just tells me how to do it in HTML. So can I do it in URL (showing an image)? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but I'll have a go: Placing an image in the url bar would be either, impossible, or very difficult. Considering each browser is a different platform, I would imagine it would need to be some sort of plugin for each browser and even then, I'm not sure it's possible. So I would say "No, it's not possible to display an image in the URL bar". Did I understand your question right?

Comment: Yes, that's my question. However we could display the image of line-chart in the URL bar. Why not trendlines? https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard

Comment: Sorry buddy, we are talking about different things :D hehe. Let's see if anyone else gets this post and can help you!

Comment: Ok, still thanks a lot! I am using the Google API now and I have displayed some images like chart lines, chart bars etc. However I don't know whether i can display the image of trendlines. If yes, it would be much easier to finish my task! ^^

Comment: If you are using the Image Chart API, then yes, you can get a URL to put in an `<img>` tag (this is, in fact, how the Image Chart API works).  If you are using the Interactive Chart API, then things get a bit more complicated, as you have to create a chart [Gadget](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/gadgets?hl=en) and embed that as a script tag on the target website.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I would like to use the Image Chart API, however, google doesn't offer this for trendlines. So does that mean: to get the trendlines,  I have to use Interactive Chart API (HTML) and then create a chart Gadget so as to put the chart on my website page? thanks.